# Issues with tap to expand on UITableView cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have a feature in my app that allows users to tap on a table view cell and it will expand to show more information. This works great but there are a few issues:

1) When I segue away from the table view, the top cell becomes expanded.
2) When I tap to expand a cell and then tap again to shrink the cell, it loses the dividing line above it until I tap a different cell.
3) When I slide to delete, the content in the expanded version of the cell overlaps the cell below it like this:

[image]

Here is my code for expanding the cell:

```
var selectedRowIndex: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: -1, inSection: 0)

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedRowIndex = indexPath
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if tableView != self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
        if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex.row {
            if cellTapped == false {
                cellTapped = true
                return 141
            } else {
                cellTapped = false
                return 68
            }
        }
    }
    return 68
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm struggling with this as well.

Comment: I didn't, no. I ended up just animating the cell so that the labels slid off the page and the notes section faded in. Looks pretty good for my needs.